# QGIS3.10, Find all points that are located on a line

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, point, geometry

Inside my .shp there are two simple layer:

- "Points_Example" (Type: Point, EPSG:25832)
- "Lines_Example" (Type: Line, EPSG:25832)

Some of the points are located exactly on the line and I'm trying to filter out these points via Python, but for some reason QGIS is always saying there are no points on my line!

```
layerLines = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Lines_Example')
layerLine = layerLines[0]

layerPoints = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Points_Example')
layerPoint = layerPoints[0]

list = []
for line in layerLine.getFeatures():
    geom = item.geometry()

    for point in layerPoint.getFeatures():
        if point.geometry().touches(geom):
            list.append(point['id'])
```

I've also tried some other methods from "QgsGeometry", but nothing seems to work! How can I solve this?

Comment: Should `geom = item.geometry()` not be `geom = line.geometry()` in your sample?

Comment: Also I don't think touches will work between points e.g the definition in PostGIS (that use Geos behind the scene) "Returns TRUE if the only points in common between g1 and g2 lie in the union of the boundaries of g1 and g2. The ST_Touches relation applies to all Area/Area, Line/Line, Line/Area, Point/Area and Point/Line pairs of relationships, but not to the Point/Point pair."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've choose to calculate the distance between lines and points. If difference is really small, the point is part of the line (I supposed due to rounding there is a small difference)

```py
layerLines = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Lines_Example')
layerLine = layerLines[0]

layerPoints = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Points_Example')
layerPoint = layerPoints[0]


list1 = []
for line in layerLine.getFeatures():
    geom = line.geometry()
    print(geom)
    for point in layerPoint.getFeatures():
        print(geom.distance(point.geometry()))
        if geom.distance(point.geometry()) < 10E-16:
            list1.append(point['id'])

print(list1)
```

You can take demo files from http://labs.webgeodatavore.com/partage/qgis-rounding.zip (Using EPSG 4326 in these files but projected coordinates will not change the logic)

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!